# Turn off thousands separator in Snowflake Snowsight

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I really like Snowflake's new Snowsight web console. One minor issue is that all the numeric columns have commas `,` as thousands separator rather than just outputting the raw number.

For example I have a bunch of UNIX epochs stored in a column called `created_time`. For debugging purposes I'd like to quickly copy and paste them into a `WHERE` clause, but I have to manually remove the commas from `1,666,719,883,332` to be `1666719883332`.

Sure it's a minor thing, but doing it several dozen times a day is really starting to up to minutes.

I realize I could cast the column to a `VARCHAR`, but I'd rather find a setting that I can turn off for this auto-thousand-separator default behavior.

Does anyone know a way to turn it off?

Here is an example:

```
create  TABLE log (
    CREATED_TIME NUMBER(38,0),
    MSG VARCHAR(20000)
);

insert into log values (1666719883332, 'example');

select * From log;
```

which outputs

| CREATED_TIME | MSG |
| --- | --- |
| 1,666,719,883,332 | example |

Comment: I'd really love to have something to just turn this thousands separator off entirely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare to be amazed! The option to show/hide the 000 separator is on the left corner

[image]

Comment: well gosh dang i'll be dipped! thank you. (in my defense i have hovered around on this page looking for expand hamburger menus and never found that one! It's like a video game. Kind of).

Comment: If there was a way to turn off the feature entirely that would be nice

Comment: @Kirby Yeah a session policy would be nice, but if you're only pasting one value, try copying from the right-hand side pane where it shows numbers without 000 separator for the selected cell

Answer (score 2):

> *I'd like to quickly copy and paste them into a WHERE clause, but I have to manually remove the commas from 1,666,719,883,332 to be 1666719883332.*

The way I use it is a preview pane and Copy button:

[image]

Comment: ah, yeah. not sure why i didn't think of that. Still I'd love to be able to hide these pesky commas.

for example, it'd be nice to select multiple cells at once